# OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument in Spark Streaming PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

Bonjour, I have an error in a Getting started code from Spark official doc, here is the code:

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
import json

sc = SparkContext('local[*]', appName="Spark Kafka streaming test")
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 60)
```

The last line is were the error come from:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                 
  File "/home/thomas/projet_perso2/kafka_log_consumer.py", line 11, in <module>                                                    
    ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 60)                                                                                                 
  File "/home/thomas/spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/streaming/context.py", line 61, in __init__          
  File "/home/thomas/spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/streaming/context.py", line 64, in _initialize_context
  File "/home/thomas/spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/streaming/context.py", line 83, in _ensure_initialized
  File "/home/thomas/spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/java_gateway.py", line 209, in ensure_callback_server_started                                                                                                                            
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

I'm using python 3.7.5

Here is my env: (just created for this example, with only pyspark installed)

```
conda list                                                                                                                      
# packages in environment at /home/thomas/miniconda3/envs/pp2:                                                                     
#                                                                                                                                   
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel                                                                  
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                        main                                                                           
ca-certificates           2019.11.27                    0                                                                           
certifi                   2019.11.28               py37_0                                                                           
libedit                   3.1.20181209         hc058e9b_0                                                                           
libffi                    3.2.1                hd88cf55_4                                                                           
libgcc-ng                 9.1.0                hdf63c60_0                                                                           
libstdcxx-ng              9.1.0                hdf63c60_0                                                                           
ncurses                   6.1                  he6710b0_1                                                                           
openssl                   1.1.1d               h7b6447c_3                                                                           
pip                       19.3.1                   py37_0                                                                           
py4j                      0.10.7                   pypi_0    pypi                                                                   
pyspark                   2.4.4                    pypi_0    pypi                                                                   
python                    3.7.5                h0371630_0                                                                           
readline                  7.0                  h7b6447c_5                                                                           
setuptools                42.0.2                   py37_0                                                                           
sqlite                    3.30.1               h7b6447c_0                                                                           
tk                        8.6.8                hbc83047_0                                                                           
wheel                     0.33.6                   py37_0                                                                           
xz                        5.2.4                h14c3975_4                                                                           
zlib                      1.2.11               h7b6447c_3
```

Edit: I'm not sure about anything but I'm starting to think it's due to WSL?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In Spark version is 2.4.4 , The entry point into all functionality in Spark is the SparkSession class not with SparkContext class. We should not declare with SparkContext in this version . 
Reference : 
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-getting-started.html

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.sql.column import Column, _to_java_column
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, struct
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
import json
import csv
import time
import os

#  Spark Streaming context :

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('pda_inst_monitor_status_update').getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 20)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but your example lead to the exact same error for me. Also, i followed the Spark doc, reference: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#initializing-streamingcontext

Comment: How you are launching spark shell . can you please share the spark version exactly . ? as this code absolutely working fine for me .

Comment: My Spark version is 2.4.4 (shown in my conda env above). However this code works fine for me too in Ubuntu 18.04, so it was probably an issue with WSL1. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: No problem . Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

This issue is probably due to WSL1, since this code works well in Ubuntu 18.04 with the exact same conda environment.